# Prolog: split a list into a list of N lists containing N items each

Tags: list, prolog, sudoku, declarative

I've been searching through the many existing Prolog questions on SO relevant to splitting but couldn't find one as generic as the one that I want. I'd like to point out that I've been able to split lists into lists of 2/3/4 elements by using 2/3/4 variables piped before a list variable. This question is different from that only because of its genericness.

So, my list will always contain N*N items, N being unknown beforehand(usually will vary from 4 to 36, yes N is also a perfect square). I want to split it into a list of N lists containing N items each because that'll allow me to treat it as a matrix, hence allowing to transpose and certain operations of that sort. I haven't really been able to get too far with the logic because I'm relatively new to declarative programming; please see below my incomplete(faulty) attempt:

```
listmodel(1,L):- L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16].
size(L,N) :- length(L,N1), N is round(sqrt(N1)).

% add_tail(+Liste, +Element, -ResultantList)
add_tail([],L,[L]).
add_tail([X|L1],L2,[X|LI]):-add_tail(L1,L2,LI).

% partition the list containing N*N items into a list of N lists containing N elements each.
% part(+Liste, +Size, -ResultantList)
part([],_,DL).
part(L,N,DL) :-
    length(P,N), % P(refix) initialized
    append(P,S,L), % S(uffix) contains rest of L, using append in (-,-,+) mode
    add_tail(DL,P,DL1), %add P(first N elements) as first element of DL.
    part(S,N,DL1).
```

Now running `?- listmodel(1,L),size(L,N),part(L,N,DL).` will produce `DL=[]` because that is what it gets initialized to in the first `add_tail` call in the `part` predicate. I can't seem to figure out how to store all elements in a list that's preserved through the recursion.

Any help/direction of any kind will be appreciated. I'm stuck here since over 23 hours 10 minutes now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
part([], _, []).
part(L, N, [DL|DLTail]) :-
   length(DL, N),
   append(DL, LTail, L),
   part(LTail, N, DLTail).
```

Base case is first/last arguments are empty lists.

Recursive step takes a fresh list of N elements, takes the first N elements from L (which will be one of the items of the third argument) and calls recursively.

Comment: Perfect! thanks for the precise answer and concise explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Want to combine versatility *and* favorable termination properties?
**Use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!**

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

First, we define
`list_prefix_n_suffix/4`. 
 `list_prefix_n_suffix(Zs,Xs,N,Ys)` is logically equivalent to both `append(Xs,Ys,Zs), length(Xs,N)` and `length(Xs,N), append(Xs,Ys,Zs)`, but has better universal termination behavior than *either*<sup>1</sup> one!

```
list_prefix_n_suffix(Zs, Xs, N, Ys) :-
   list_prefix_n0_n_suffix(Zs, Xs, 0,N, Ys).

list_prefix_n0_n_suffix(Zs, Xs, N0,N, Ys) :-
   zcompare(Order, N0, N),
   rel_list_prefix_n0_n_suffix(Order, Zs, Xs, N0,N, Ys).

rel_list_prefix_n0_n_suffix(=, Ys, [], _,_, Ys).
rel_list_prefix_n0_n_suffix(<, [Z|Zs], [Z|Xs], N0,N, Ys) :-
   N1 #= N0 + 1,
   list_prefix_n0_n_suffix(Zs, Xs, N1,N, Ys).
```

Some sample queries for `list_prefix_n_suffix/4`:

```
?- list_prefix_n_suffix([a,b,c], Xs,-1, Ys).
false.                                          % OK: too small

?- list_prefix_n_suffix([a,b,c], Xs, 0, Ys).
Xs = [], Ys = [a,b,c].                          % succeeds deterministically

?- list_prefix_n_suffix([a,b,c], Xs, 4, Ys).
false.                                          % OK: too big

?- list_prefix_n_suffix([a,b,c], Xs, N, Ys).
   Xs = []     , N = 0, Ys = [a,b,c]
;  Xs = [a]    , N = 1, Ys =   [b,c]
;  Xs = [a,b]  , N = 2, Ys =     [c]
;  Xs = [a,b,c], N = 3, Ys =      []
;  false.                                       % terminates universally
```

Based upon above `list_prefix_n_suffix/4` we define `list_rows_width/3`:

```
list_rows_width([], [], _N).
list_rows_width([E|Es0], [[R|Rs]|Rss], N) :-
   list_prefix_n_suffix([E|Es0], [R|Rs], N, Es),
   list_rows_width(Es, Rss, N).
```

Sample queries using `list_rows_width/3`:

```
?- list_rows_width([a,b,c,d,e,f], Rows, 4).
false.                                          % OK: 6 is not divisible by 4

?- list_rows_width([a,b,c,d,e,f], Rows, 3).
Rows = [[a,b,c],[d,e,f]].                       % succeeds deterministically

?- list_rows_width([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l], Rows, N).
   N =  1, Rows = [[a],[b],[c],[d],[e],[f],[g],[h],[i],[j],[k],[l]]
;  N =  2, Rows = [[a,  b],[c,  d],[e,  f],[g,  h],[i,  j],[k,  l]]
;  N =  3, Rows = [[a,  b,  c],[d,  e,  f],[g,  h,  i],[j,  k,  l]]
;  N =  4, Rows = [[a,  b,  c,  d],[e,  f,  g,  h],[i,  j,  k,  l]]
;  N =  6, Rows = [[a,  b,  c,  d,  e,  f],[g,  h,  i,  j,  k,  l]]
;  N = 12, Rows = [[a,  b,  c,  d,  e,  f,  g,  h,  i,  j,  k,  l]]
;  false.                                       % terminates universally
```

Works just like it should!

---

<sup>**Footnote 1:** Without resorting to using alternative control-flow mechanisms like [prolog-coroutining](/questions/tagged/prolog-coroutining).</sup>